# Selenium open pop up window [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a link by:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='javascript:openhistory('AXS0077')']").click()
```

This works nice if the link opens in a new window but in this case the link actually opens a pop up window. When I try clicking the link with this method, using selenium it gives me an error:

> Message: u"The given selector
>   a[href='javascript:openhistory('AXS0077')'] is either invalid or does
>   not result in a WebElement. The following error
>   occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was
>   specified"

Is this not the right way ? because
I think there may be some different way to deal with pop windows.

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("""a[href='javascript:openhistory("AXS0077")']""").click()` or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("""a[href="javascript:openhistory('AXS0077')"]""").click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css selector could be more generic, perhaps:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href^='javascript']").click()
```

You've got all kinds of crazy overlapping quotation marks there. You're probably confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have more success `using find_by_xpath`

Take this site as an example [popups](http://www.globalrph.com/davescripts/popup.htm)

I use `firebug` to inspect the `element` and get the `xpath`.

Then using the following works perfectly.

```
from selenium import webdriver

baseurl="http://www.globalrph.com/davescripts/popup.htm"

dr = webdriver.Firefox()
dr.get(baseurl)
dr.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/center/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a").click()
```